# JSONObject ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, json, maven, intellij-idea, classnotfoundexception

I am working in IntelliJ and using Maven. I have a class that uses `JSONObject`:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

try {
  JSONObject documentObj = new JSONObject(document);
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Failed to convert JSON String to JSON Object.", e);
}
```

Maven dependency in the pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.json</groupId>
  <artifactId>json</artifactId>
  <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
```

I can do a `mvn clean package` and builds successfully. But when I try to run it, I get:

> Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject

Is there anything else I'm missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Did you checked that jar is in your classpath or in the war file ?

Comment: I have my project in intelliJ, and I run it using a bash script from the command line in linux.

Comment: Alright, I got it--y'all were right, I didn't have it in my classpath. There were two variables set in the bash script: LIBJARS, the jars required by the job, and the CLASSPATH. I set it in the CLASSPATH, but in fact it was needed in the LIBJARS variable.... the joys of taking over others' code. :)
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Add [json jar](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/json/json/20090211/json-20090211.jar) to your classpath

or use `java -classpath json.jar ClassName`

Or add this to your maven pom.xml depedencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Alright, I got it--y'all were right, I didn't have it in my classpath. There were two variables set in the bash script: LIBJARS, the jars required by the job, and the CLASSPATH. I set it in the CLASSPATH, but in fact it was needed in the LIBJARS variable.... the joys of taking over others' code. :)
Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is the latest dependency & it don't seems to have "import org.json.JSONObject;". Could you please guide ASAP?
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
 <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
 <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 10):

As of today (15th July 2020), you need to use latest maven repository as per below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20200518</version>
</dependency>
```

For any new version in the future, you can check it here:

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

Then simply replace **20200518** with latest **new version value**.

Answer (score 5):

Using the latest maven dependency solved the issue for me

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20171018</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Originally I was using `net.sf.json-lib` but it was creating issues with JSONArray whenever I try to use `.put()` method

Following solved my issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

Although I am not big fan of using `LATEST` but since its a numeric version number, instead of more understndable versioning, so I found this one working for me.